# Jquery slideUp menu disappears after slideDown

Tags: jquery

I'm working on a menu that should slide down when I click on an anchor `<a>`, and it should slide up when I click on the `<body>` of the page (the `<a>` tag is included in the body).
I'm currently using jQuery.

The problem is that after the first 2 click's (first on the  tag result: the menu appears; second click on the `<body>`), the menu disappears, but when I click again on the `<a>` tag the menu slides both down an up at the same time?

Here is the code:

```
$(function() {
    $('.sch_option a').click(function() {           
        $('.sch_option .sch_more_option_extend').slideDown(150, function(){             
            $('body').click(function() {
                $('.sch_option .sch_more_option_extend').slideUp(100);          
            }); 
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you click on the a, you need to stop propagation of the click event.

```
$('.sch_option a').click(function(e) {
     e.stopPropagation();
     $('.sch_option .sch_more_option_extend').slideDown(150); 
});

$('body').click(function(){
        $('.sch_option .sch_more_option_extend').slideUp(100);
});
```

Comment: You should definitely move the body's click method outside of the anchor tag's click like Jose is saying.

Answer (score 0):

You bind to `body` same function over and over. Try unbinding it first;

```
$('body').unbind('click').click(function(){
    $('.sch_option .sch_more_option_extend').slideUp(100);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't really use `$('body').` here coz your menu is already a child of `body`, what you can do is to track the `offset` of the click and then hide the menu.